# Bootstrap navigation bar with Jade not displaying

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am using `JADE`. The `burger` sign on the top right hand corner is not getting displayed. (The burger like sign that appears when the site is in responsive mode.)

I have attached my code, Can someone tell me what's wrong ?

```
div.navbar.navbar-fixed-top(role='navigation')
        div.navbar-header
            button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.navbar-collapse')
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
            a.navbar-brand(href="#")
                h1 brand


        div.collapse.navbar-collapse

            ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                li.active
                    a.navmenulink(href="#1") about
                li
                    a.navmenulink(href="#2") menu
                li
                    a.navmenulink(href="#3") Contact
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a html to jade online converter I got different result, which generates to this https://jsfiddle.net/yh8jbyoh/

```
nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
  .container
    .navbar-header
      button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbar', aria-expanded='false', aria-controls='navbar')
        span.sr-only Toggle navigation
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
      a.navbar-brand(href='#') Project name
    #navbar.collapse.navbar-collapse
      ul.nav.navbar-nav
        li.active
          a(href='#') Home
        li
          a(href='#about') About
        li
          a(href='#contact') Contact
```